Adding layer from Internet to QGIS
If I want to add layers that are presented on an internet site how do I do it easiest, if possibly in a form that I can use or at least snap to
Examples:

https://karta.habo.se/spatialmap,
https://karta.nassjo.se/spatialmap
https://kartan.linkoping.se/spatialmap


There has to exist a WMS or WFS besides the webmap. You can't simply add some geodata from a webmap, there are some standards, which have to be met for QGIS to "understand" the data.

The data displayed on these web maps are served via a WMS server.
You can find the URL fired by inspecting the web page.
Go to the web page, right click and choose inspect.
Then go to the network tab, press Ctrl + F5 to reload the page and you will see all the requests fired to load the page. In the list, you can find the WMS request.

From what I can see, the service is exposed at this URL which doesn't need authentication so you can use this to add the WMS layers in QGIS:
https://karta.nassjo.se/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICENAME=csm_standard_profile

You won't be able to snap to these data in QGIS as there are WMS (eg. raster) layers.

Thanks, am i just changing nassjo to habo/linkoping? Can i see if its WFS or WMS server? and how do i find the url?

Edited to add how to find the WMS server URL. If it's not clear, I recommand you to dig a little bit in WMS protocol and how it works.

I will do. Do you have anything for dummies? If i try that on https://kartan.linkoping.se/spatialmap? it has 4 different WMS? , tile5-8 ?   https://tile8-kartan.linkoping.se/tilecache/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1. Do I have to add 4 WMS layers or can I combine them?

you can start from here and browse external links: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service

With a short analysis of url fired for linkoping, you can build this url for QGIS: https://kartan.linkoping.se/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICENAME=lkkarta

the tile 5-8 urls returns the images to show the basemap. I guess this is not what you are looking for.

thanks, what about this one ?https://addspatial.sokigo.com/SMART/profile/28705a12-8b6f-46f0-a3b7-5aaf1613347f/a67c2fdd-fd84-4e9a-bfda-f413a9983779/662d67ac-c318-47b1-a086-9b7084a1fe03?language=sv
